# Not clear/sharp font in Windows after connecting it thru Remote desktop for the 1st time

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, fonts, cleartype

Today I've logged in thru remote session to my Windows 7 machine for the 1st time. After that I came back and on started working on site (physically on box), bud noticed immediately that my font is strange. I've reassured that ClearType settings are set.
I don't know why it happen and how to restore it to be as it was. It's visible ex. on Google Chrome address bar

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this happening for all apps or just Chrome? (i.e.: try windows explorer, IE etc.)

Comment: Like the answers at the bottom say typing about:restart into the Chrome address bar and hitting enter worked for me.

Comment: Discord and Chrome fonts get demolished after disconnecting from RDP. Still holds true in Windows 10.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Make sure "Font smoothing" is checked in the "Experience" tab (MS RDC Client), if it doesn't help, please log off current user from the start menu and try again.

Comment: It's silly, but restarting my machine helped. Logging off not, yet it's OK answer for me.

Comment: i dont have an experience tab. maybe because im on Win7?

Comment: This answer talks about smoothing the text while RDPing while the question was more about *post* RDPing.

Comment: This, combined with Mladen B's chrome restart tip, works perfectly!

Comment: One also needs to adjust "Adjust ClearType Text" on remote machine. Please read the below article for full details.

https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/solutions/articles/4000086092-enable-font-smoothing-when-connecting-via-rdp

Answer (score 79):

What helped me is to type the following in the Google Chrome's address bar :

```
about:restart
```

and press Enter. Chrome will restart and reopen all your tabs and your font smoothing should again work at this point.

Comment: Thank you! Been searching high & low for a way to get rid of the Roboto font after remote desktop session.

Comment: You have no idea how long I've been looking for this solution and yet it's so simple. Thank you!

Comment: I wish I could upvote this post every time I remote in to my computer and then need to look up this solution to fix my browser. This answer has helped me countless of times!

Comment: This should be accepted answer!

Comment: Great tip! very convenient way to restart chrome.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the enthusiasm for this answer... Good if you only/mostly use Chrome I guses, but I use a lot of other programs, and they mostly continue looking terrible after an RDP session.

Comment: Make sure only one blank tab is opened or it `may` not work

Comment: I had this issue in VSCode too, I just had to restart it.

Comment: It works. I remote to Windows via Remmina (Ubuntu). Fonts in Chrome is ugly, while in PyCharm is okay.
This fixes the Chrome font problem.

Answer (score 15):

I resolved by changing the profile in the Performance configuration tab of Remote Desktop, from automatic quality detection to `10 LAN` (the `Font Smoothing` checkbox got activated):

[image]

Comment: and after this about:restart from chrome tab, helps me to fix the issue. thankQ